# MySQL SELECT WHERE numerous columns are less than one column, unless that column is zero

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a price notification app and struggling with how to get a query to work as desired.

I have 4 price columns. PURCHASEPRICE, CURRENTPRICE, AMAZONPRICE, EBAYPRICE

Other than PURCHASEPRICE these columns may be 0.00 in many instances (such as a product match was not found between the retailer and Amazon and/or eBay)

This query seems to work OK without the additional column that needs to be added now. (Although I don't know that this is the best way to do it)

```
SELECT * 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE (CURRENTPRICE < PURCHASEPRICE AND CURRENTPRICE > 0) 
    OR (AMAZONPRICE < PURCHASEPRICE AND AMAZONPRICE > 0) 
    OR (EBAYPRICE < PURCHASEPRICE AND EBAYPRICE > 0) 
    AND OVER30DAYS != '1'
```

However, I need to work in another column for the price when a user is notified that the price changed, such as NOTIFIEDPRICE and only retrieve results if NOTIFIEDPRICE is greater than PURCHASEPRICE, or AMAZONPRICE, or EBAYPRICE and when NOTIFIEDPRICE is not = 0.

Is there a way to do this in the query? Or a better way?

Thanks!

Edited to add structure & sample data as requested.

For the rows in the sample data, the following SKU numbers should be retrieved or not, because of these scenarios:

- NOT retrieved for 247868, 539189, and 3745320 because notified price is less than all other prices, so
  user has previously been notified and the price they were notfied at
  has not been beat.
- Retrieved for 3733482 because eBay price is less than both purchase price and
  notified price, so even though user was notified when price dropped
  to 22, it is still less than when they were notified so we want to
  notify them again of a further price drop.
- Retrieved for 5292842 because current price is less than purchase price, and
  notified price of 0 means user hasn't been notified yet
- Retrieved for 5472824 because Amazon price is less than purchase price.
  Notified price of 0 means user hasn't been notified yet.
- Retrieved for 13553953 because eBay price is less than purchase price and
  notified price of 0 means user hasn't been notified yet

Hopefully that helps to clarify what I am trying to accomplish.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `orders`
--

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `ORDERNUMBER` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `CUSTOMERNAME` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ORDERDATE` date NOT NULL,
  `SKU` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UPC` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `MANUFACTURER` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `MANUFACTURERID` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `NAME` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `PURCHASEPRICE` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `CURRENTPRICE` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AMAZONPRICE` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EBAYPRICE` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOTIFIEDPRICE` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QUANTITY` smallint(3) NOT NULL,
  `OVER30DAYS` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `orders`
--

INSERT INTO `orders` (`ORDERNUMBER`, `EMAIL`, `CUSTOMERNAME`, `ORDERDATE`, `SKU`, `UPC`, `MANUFACTURER`, `MANUFACTURERID`, `NAME`, `PURCHASEPRICE`, `CURRENTPRICE`, `AMAZONPRICE`, `EBAYPRICE`, `NOTIFIEDPRICE`, `QUANTITY`, `OVER30DAYS`) VALUES
(17104115, 'user@user.com', 'User Name', '2018-05-27', 247868, '764017000018', 'New World Marine', 'FX-8', 'New World Marine Fendergrip Fender Adjuster', '15.99', '12.99', '0.00', '0.00', '11.00', 0, 0),
(17104115, 'user@user.com', 'User Name', '2018-05-27', 539189, '071247859324', 'Star Brite', '085932PW', 'Star Brite Nonskid Deck Cleaner with PTEF, Quart', '11.39', '18.99', '7.00', '0.00', '6.00', 0, 0),
(17104115, 'user@user.com', 'User Name', '2018-05-27', 3733482, '632085050252', 'Blue Sea Systems', '5025', 'Blue Sea Systems 6-Circuit Fuse Block with Ground Bus and Cover', '38.39', '47.99', '0.00', '21.00', '22.00', 0, 0),
(17104115, 'user@user.com', 'User Name', '2018-05-27', 3745320, '810062001163', 'Woody Wax', 'WW16', 'Woody Wax Fiberglass & Nonskid Deck Wax', '39.99', '39.99', '0.00', '38.00', '37.00', 0, 0),
(17104115, 'user@user.com', 'User Name', '2018-05-27', 5292842, '788026089949', 'Standard Horizon', 'MMB-84', 'Standard Horizon Flush Mount Kit for VHF Radios', '16.99', '14.99', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', 0, 0),
(17104115, 'user@user.com', 'User Name', '2018-05-27', 5472824, '810062005000', 'Woody Wax', 'WSH32', 'Woody Wax Ultra Pine Wash & Wax Boat Soap', '24.99', '24.99', '22.00', '0.00', '0.00', 0, 0),
(17104115, 'user@user.com', 'User Name', '2018-05-27', 13553953, '858693003019', 'Stern Saver', 'SS01-BW', 'Stern Saver Transducer Mounting Block', '49.99', '49.99', '0.00', '30.00', '0.00', 0, 0);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `orders`
--
ALTER TABLE `orders`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `ORDERNUMBER` (`ORDERNUMBER`,`SKU`);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Yes it can be done in a query, and yes there might be a better way to do it. But without your table schema, some sample data, it's impossible to tell for sure. Edit your question and add the schema of the table along with some sample data.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I have edited per your request. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your requirements. Also, I had to modify your example data to have rows that satisfied the two different scenarios.

You can see the DB Fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=30RDOJ8KxS)

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
    if((CURRENTPRICE < PURCHASEPRICE AND CURRENTPRICE > 0) 
    OR (AMAZONPRICE < PURCHASEPRICE AND AMAZONPRICE > 0) 
    OR (EBAYPRICE < PURCHASEPRICE AND EBAYPRICE > 0) AND OVER30DAYS != '1',1,0) as `test1`,
    if(((NOTIFIEDPRICE > PURCHASEPRICE AND PURCHASEPRICE != 0) OR
      (NOTIFIEDPRICE > AMAZONPRICE AND AMAZONPRICE != 0) OR
      (NOTIFIEDPRICE > EBAYPRICE AND EBAYPRICE != 0)) AND
      NOTIFIEDPRICE != 0,1,0) as `test2`,
      `orders`.*
FROM `orders` 
WHERE ((CURRENTPRICE < PURCHASEPRICE AND CURRENTPRICE > 0) 
    OR (AMAZONPRICE < PURCHASEPRICE AND AMAZONPRICE > 0) 
    OR (EBAYPRICE < PURCHASEPRICE AND EBAYPRICE > 0) 
    AND OVER30DAYS != '1')
    OR
    (
      ((NOTIFIEDPRICE > PURCHASEPRICE AND PURCHASEPRICE != 0) OR
      (NOTIFIEDPRICE > AMAZONPRICE AND AMAZONPRICE != 0) OR
      (NOTIFIEDPRICE > EBAYPRICE AND EBAYPRICE != 0)) AND
      NOTIFIEDPRICE != 0
      )
```

---

**EDIT**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbb3a6/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `ORDERNUMBER` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `CUSTOMERNAME` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ORDERDATE` date NOT NULL,
  `SKU` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UPC` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `MANUFACTURER` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `MANUFACTURERID` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `NAME` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `PURCHASEPRICE` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `CURRENTPRICE` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AMAZONPRICE` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EBAYPRICE` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOTIFIEDPRICE` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QUANTITY` smallint(3) NOT NULL,
  `OVER30DAYS` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `orders`
--

INSERT INTO `orders` (`ORDERNUMBER`, `EMAIL`, `CUSTOMERNAME`, `ORDERDATE`, `SKU`, `UPC`, `MANUFACTURER`, `MANUFACTURERID`, `NAME`, `PURCHASEPRICE`, `CURRENTPRICE`, `AMAZONPRICE`, `EBAYPRICE`, `NOTIFIEDPRICE`, `QUANTITY`, `OVER30DAYS`) VALUES
(17104115, 'user@user.com', 'User Name', '2018-05-27', 247868, '764017000018', 'New World Marine', 'FX-8', 'New World Marine Fendergrip Fender Adjuster', '15.99', '12.99', '0.00', '0.00', '11.00', 0, 0),
(17104115, 'user@user.com', 'User Name', '2018-05-27', 539189, '071247859324', 'Star Brite', '085932PW', 'Star Brite Nonskid Deck Cleaner with PTEF, Quart', '11.39', '18.99', '7.00', '0.00', '6.00', 0, 0),
(17104115, 'user@user.com', 'User Name', '2018-05-27', 3733482, '632085050252', 'Blue Sea Systems', '5025', 'Blue Sea Systems 6-Circuit Fuse Block with Ground Bus and Cover', '38.39', '47.99', '0.00', '21.00', '22.00', 0, 0),
(17104115, 'user@user.com', 'User Name', '2018-05-27', 3745320, '810062001163', 'Woody Wax', 'WW16', 'Woody Wax Fiberglass & Nonskid Deck Wax', '39.99', '39.99', '0.00', '38.00', '37.00', 0, 0),
(17104115, 'user@user.com', 'User Name', '2018-05-27', 5292842, '788026089949', 'Standard Horizon', 'MMB-84', 'Standard Horizon Flush Mount Kit for VHF Radios', '16.99', '14.99', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', 0, 0),
(17104115, 'user@user.com', 'User Name', '2018-05-27', 5472824, '810062005000', 'Woody Wax', 'WSH32', 'Woody Wax Ultra Pine Wash & Wax Boat Soap', '24.99', '24.99', '22.00', '0.00', '0.00', 0, 0),
(17104115, 'user@user.com', 'User Name', '2018-05-27', 13553953, '858693003019', 'Stern Saver', 'SS01-BW', 'Stern Saver Transducer Mounting Block', '49.99', '49.99', '0.00', '30.00', '0.00', 0, 0);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `orders`
--
ALTER TABLE `orders`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `ORDERNUMBER` (`ORDERNUMBER`,`SKU`);
COMMIT;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    if((CURRENTPRICE < PURCHASEPRICE AND CURRENTPRICE > 0) 
    OR (AMAZONPRICE < PURCHASEPRICE AND AMAZONPRICE > 0) 
    OR (EBAYPRICE < PURCHASEPRICE AND EBAYPRICE > 0) AND NOT OVER30DAYS,1,0) as `test1`,
    if(((NOTIFIEDPRICE > PURCHASEPRICE AND PURCHASEPRICE != 0) OR
      (NOTIFIEDPRICE > AMAZONPRICE AND AMAZONPRICE != 0) OR
      (NOTIFIEDPRICE > EBAYPRICE AND EBAYPRICE != 0)) AND
      NOTIFIEDPRICE != 0,1,0) as `test2`,
      `orders`.*
FROM `orders` 
WHERE ((CURRENTPRICE < PURCHASEPRICE AND CURRENTPRICE > 0) 
    OR (AMAZONPRICE < PURCHASEPRICE AND AMAZONPRICE > 0) 
    OR (EBAYPRICE < PURCHASEPRICE AND EBAYPRICE > 0) 
    AND NOT OVER30DAYS)
    OR
    (
      ((NOTIFIEDPRICE > PURCHASEPRICE AND PURCHASEPRICE != 0) OR
      (NOTIFIEDPRICE > AMAZONPRICE AND AMAZONPRICE != 0) OR
      (NOTIFIEDPRICE > EBAYPRICE AND EBAYPRICE != 0)) AND
      NOTIFIEDPRICE != 0
      )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbb3a6/2/0)**:

```
| test1 | test2 | ORDERNUMBER |         EMAIL | CUSTOMERNAME |  ORDERDATE |      SKU |          UPC |     MANUFACTURER | MANUFACTURERID |                                                            NAME | PURCHASEPRICE | CURRENTPRICE | AMAZONPRICE | EBAYPRICE | NOTIFIEDPRICE | QUANTITY | OVER30DAYS |
|-------|-------|-------------|---------------|--------------|------------|----------|--------------|------------------|----------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|---------------|--------------|-------------|-----------|---------------|----------|------------|
|     1 |     0 |    17104115 | user@user.com |    User Name | 2018-05-27 |   247868 | 764017000018 | New World Marine |           FX-8 |                     New World Marine Fendergrip Fender Adjuster |         15.99 |        12.99 |           0 |         0 |            11 |        0 |      false |
|     1 |     0 |    17104115 | user@user.com |    User Name | 2018-05-27 |   539189 | 071247859324 |       Star Brite |       085932PW |                Star Brite Nonskid Deck Cleaner with PTEF, Quart |         11.39 |        18.99 |           7 |         0 |             6 |        0 |      false |
|     1 |     1 |    17104115 | user@user.com |    User Name | 2018-05-27 |  3733482 | 632085050252 | Blue Sea Systems |           5025 | Blue Sea Systems 6-Circuit Fuse Block with Ground Bus and Cover |         38.39 |        47.99 |           0 |        21 |            22 |        0 |      false |
|     1 |     0 |    17104115 | user@user.com |    User Name | 2018-05-27 |  3745320 | 810062001163 |        Woody Wax |           WW16 |                         Woody Wax Fiberglass & Nonskid Deck Wax |         39.99 |        39.99 |           0 |        38 |            37 |        0 |      false |
|     1 |     0 |    17104115 | user@user.com |    User Name | 2018-05-27 |  5292842 | 788026089949 | Standard Horizon |         MMB-84 |                 Standard Horizon Flush Mount Kit for VHF Radios |         16.99 |        14.99 |           0 |         0 |             0 |        0 |      false |
|     1 |     0 |    17104115 | user@user.com |    User Name | 2018-05-27 |  5472824 | 810062005000 |        Woody Wax |          WSH32 |                       Woody Wax Ultra Pine Wash & Wax Boat Soap |         24.99 |        24.99 |          22 |         0 |             0 |        0 |      false |
|     1 |     0 |    17104115 | user@user.com |    User Name | 2018-05-27 | 13553953 | 858693003019 |      Stern Saver |        SS01-BW |                           Stern Saver Transducer Mounting Block |         49.99 |        49.99 |           0 |        30 |             0 |        0 |      false |
```

I'm not sure which records in the result are incorrect per your requirements. Yes you could filter in the PHP code, or just use the portion of the where clause that returns the rows you want, or modify the order by to sort by the test results. I included test1 and test2 mainly for debug purposes, and to see which part of the where clause pertains to each row returned.

Comment: Thanks for your help here. Your query is pretty close to what I'm trying to accomplish. Let me try to expand a bit more - this query creates the test1/test2 columns, which then I could filter against in PHP, but I could just do that against the NOTIFIEDPRICE column to begin with. Is there a way to do that within this query? It's stretching my capacity/experience. The other thing is that it doesn't quite seem to be getting it quite correctly. I will edit my question to change the data, and explain which rows should be included/excluded in the response to hopefully help clarify. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer. It seems that the DBfiddle code went away, so I've updated my answer with a link to a SQLFiddle example, and included the results/code from that in my answer.